# Creating spheres In Matlab that change surface color depending data

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a series of randomly distributed spheres in Matlab, three will be three sub-sets. I would like each subset to have a different color. I am using a structure because each sphere will also have different properties associated with it. I tried using colormap, and set(...'FaceColor'..) but am having some difficulty. Please Help.

```
for n = 1:100
    Bslice.cell(n).index = n; 
    Bslice.cell(n).type = 'Tyep1'; % Type2, Type3
     Bslice.cell(n).location = round(rand(1, 3)*10);
end 

%%
[x,y,z] = sphere;

for n = 1:10
    hold on 
    grid on
    surfl(x-Bslice.cell(n).location(1), y-Bslice.cell(n).location(2), z-        Bslice.cell(n).location(3), ones(size(); 
    shading interp
    % colormap(hot(100))
end
```

Comment: Hi Cerberus, and welcome to scicomp!  Excellent question!  I've been wondering about how to do this myself too.

Comment: Hi, Cerberus, I wonder why have you accepted my answer, you haven't said which one is you need so that I could add more details about tweaking the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me be clear, `FaceColor` assigns a specific *single* color to every surface in that `patch` object drawn by `surfl`, and you would lose the lighting info.

If you want to modify `FaceColor` for each ball, you could add a `color` to indicate the color(here I use the distance to the origin), rescale it to an RGB vector(also I assume `Bslice.cell(n).location` is the direction of the lighting source in `surfl`)

```
clear all;close all;
for n = 1:100
    Bslice.cell(n).index = n; 
    Bslice.cell(n).type = 'Tyep1'; % Type2, Type3
    Bslice.cell(n).location = round(rand(1, 3)*10);
    color(n) = sqrt(sum(Bslice.cell(n).location.^2));
end 
color = repmat(color,3,1)/max(color);

[x,y,z] = sphere;

for n = 1:10
    hold on 
    grid on
    h(n) = surfl(x-Bslice.cell(n).location(1), ...
          y-Bslice.cell(n).location(2), ...
          z-Bslice.cell(n).location(3), ...
          Bslice.cell(n).location); 
set(h(n),'FaceColor',color(:,n))
view(3);
end
```

[image: sphere1]

Or you mean for each set you are using a different `colormap` like this?

[image: sphere2]

[image: sphere3]

[image: sphere4]

Comment: This is very helpful. I will have a range of data [1 to 100] for each Sphere and eventually want the spheres to change color based on their range value. 1 = balck, 100= bright yellow. also Bslice.cell(n).location is not a lighting parameter but the location of the sphere in three denominational space.